# Not getting Javascript,css files with RequestDispatcher

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

I working with servlet application my folder structure is :

```
WEB-INF ->
        -> Test
             -> index.html
             -> index.js
             -> index.css
```

Inside .java file I am loading index.html file as follow:

```
    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("WEB-INF/Test/index.html"); 
    dispatcher.include(request, response);
    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
```

This is loading index.html file successfully on browser. But problem is with css , js files. This files are not loading in the resource ,I have loaded those as follow inside **index.html** :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css" />
<script src="index.js"></script>
```

The error I am getting is `404 resource not found error.` So am I missing anything ? or should I take some other approach ?

Comment: is this css file is `styles.css` or `index.css`. you should do either `include` or `forward`.

Comment: @Satya: Its index.css , I have edited question

Answer (score 2):

Don't put those files in /WEB-INF. Move them up one level.

The /WEB-INF folder is meant to hold configuration files, the compiled application (/WEB-INF/classes) and the application dependencies (/WEB-INF/lib).

Comment: you mean in WebContent folder?

Comment: I moved those files to upper level but still there is same scenario.

Comment: I don't know anything about your server except for the information you provided about WEB-INF. If WebContent is the parent folder to WEB-INF, then yes.

Comment: Update your question with the specific Tomcat configuration. I gave you a generic answer based on the servlet specification.

Comment: Remember, anything inside WEB-INF is only accessible to the Java code. The web browser is making a separate request for the CSS and JS files. You either have to make the CSS and JS files public web content, or you have to write Java code to forward to the files.

Comment: I can only give you an answer according to the [standard](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnadx.html). Public files exist in the same directory as WEB-INF (not inside WEB-INF, next to it). If that doesn't work, you really should edit this question with details of the Tomcat configuration.